# Django paypal : Can't reach the paypal payment process

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-paypal

I'm using django-paypal and I can't access to the paypal payment process.

I have my view with the paypal form but nothing happens after clicking on buy on paypal button.

here is my code : (view)

```
def paypal(request):
amount = 0
cart_item = get_cart_items(request)
all_product_in_cart = CartItem.objects.filter(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
for cart in all_product_in_cart:
    amount += cart.product.price * cart.quantity
# What you want the button to do.
paypal_dict = {
    "business": "xxx@xxx.com",
    "amount": amount,
    'currencycode':  'EUR',
    "item_name": cart.product.name,
    "invoice": "unique-invoice-id",
    "notify_url": "/ipn/",
    "return_url": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("boutiquecar.views.success_payment")),
    "cancel_return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("boutiquecar.views.cancel_payment")),
}

# Create the instance.
form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="cart")
return render(request, "shop_paypal/payment.html", {
    "form": form,
    'amount': amount,
    })
```

and template :

```
<h1>You are about to buy for {{ amount }} €</h1>
<form method="post" action="{{ paypal_url }}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <tbody>
        {% if errors %}<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">{{ errors }}</td></tr>{% endif %}
        {{ form.render }}
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Normally As I saw in other posts, It would work, but I can't figur out how to fix it !

if u can help it would be great ! :) thanks in advance

Comment: what is `{{ paypal_url }}`? This blog post might help you. http://od-eon.com/blogs/nai/django-paypal-step-step-integration/

Comment: paypal_url is just a try, before there were nothing. I did try the step by step integration, but I can't find out the issue

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I have no error, Just when I click at the submit button, Nothing happen. That's my problem ! ^^

Comment: Well then the problem is because the action url is empty. It should be posting to the paypal sandbox url

Comment: It was right ! Thank you for your answer :)! I though django paypal Handled the form.